# How To Adjust Speed of MoveByOffset In Selenium Using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

My code is:

```
By slider_humidity = By.XPath("ExampleXpath");
var hSlider = driver.FindElement(slider_humidity);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(hSlider, 0, 0); //this will make it to start at 0,0 of the slider
action.ClickAndHold(); //don't pass the element, now it will click current mouse location which is (0,0)
action.MoveByOffset(pixelstomove, 0); // move by 30 pixel from 0
action.Build().Perform();
```

It seem to be too fast for my targeted website and I need to change the speed of it. It basically goes from point 0 to the given point instantly. I however would like it to slide the slider slowly.
Also alternatives way using Javascript inside C# would be apprecited, as long as I can adjust the speed to my wishes.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to describe how it currently behaves, and how it doesn't meet your needs? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No. As stated, it pushes the slider, but I can't adjust the speed, which I however want. I need to slow it down, because it pushes the slider in less than a second.

Comment: Is there a problem with the slider moving too fast?

Comment: It works. But this is not what I want. It is too fast for my purpose. If you don't know how to slow it down, please don't write anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
By slider_humidity = By.XPath("ExampleXpath");
var hSlider = driver.FindElement(slider_humidity);
PointerInputDevice mouse = new PointerInputDevice();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(hSlider, 0, 0) //this will make it to start at 0,0 of the slider
      .ClickAndHold() //don't pass the element, now it will click current mouse location which is (0,0)
      .tick(mouse.CreatePointerMove(hSlider, pixelstomove, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))) // Move by <pixelstomove> in x-offset
      .Build()
      .Perform();
```